# "Build" an XML file that collates all XIncludes

Tags: xml, gradle, build, xinclude

I am currently using XInclude to reduce the amount of duplication in my XML log4j2 configuration files.  However, I was wondering if there is a tool that will collate all of the files XInclude-ed (...) and produce a single XML file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="debug" monitorInterval="30" strict="true"
    name="Log4JParentConfig" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">

    <xi:include href="log4jProperties.xml"/>
    <xi:include href="log4jAppenders.xml"/>
    <xi:include href="log4jLoggers.xml"/>

</Configuration>
```

Using XInclude is not a rock-solid requirement.  My current build tool is Gradle.